# Milk, regeneration properties for devil fruit users?

Tags: one-piece

Does milk offer regenerative capabilities? I've never seen it in the anime but in the newest chapter 858 of the manga the following scene is shown.
[image: Luffy growing a tooth back]

Now, I haven't been reading the manga long I just started reading after the dressrosa arc but I watched the anime up to that point and I don't recall ever seeing anything like this.

Is this a devil fruit thing? A gag?

Comment: yeah, i also don't remember it has been mentioned as a "healing" mechanism besides fixing brooks bones because of the calcium it contains. I think it just a gag based on the milks health myths and that is why it  managed to restore luffys teeth. I think it works only in Brook's case.

Comment: Yeah I got kind of disappointed. I mean Luffy has gotten several notable scars over the years that show testament to the trials he went through on his journey to be a pirate king the scar on his eye, the scar on his chest, the missing tooth. Then `oh his tooth can just grow back because milk`.

Comment: @Kaz Well his eye scar is self inflicted as a child.  The chest occurred/represents the death of Ace.  The tooth is... compared to the others... insignificant.

Comment: @Proxy it didn't really work in Brooks case previously if I remember correctly.  Brook thought/felt it did and Chopper called him out on that.  Now... rule of funny.

Comment: @kaine I dunno it was a pretty brutal fight between him and Sanji. And it's a representation of his growth. To be able to hold on to his friends. But in terms of the other two you are right. I'll leave this up in case Oda does an AMA or something and there is an actual reason for it

Comment: @KazRodgers yeah, on one side i understand why oda did it and realistically this was the only "right" way luffy could have gained his tooth back so i'm not surprised why oda pulled it off. For me personally i would have loved it if luffy stayed without it, it gives a bit of more character to him and serves as a remainder of how easily things can turn wrong. A shame would have been another nice way to distance itself from other shounen manga heroes

Comment: Calcium is good for your bones

Comment: @JTR correct but teeth are not bones they are enamel

Comment: @KazRodgers yeah, [but calcium also good for your teeth](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=is+drinking+milk+good+for+teeth%3F&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) XD

Comment: @KazRodgers by the way, it's more a gag for Brook I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a gag and actually just applies for Brook and Luffy. The calcium in the milk is good for bones and Brook is nothing but bones (It is mentioned at Thriller Bark, even in the anime) and Luffy has huge regenerative powers whenever he eats or drinks (remember Alabasta when he pumped water in his almost dead dry body).